# Why is SQL server not using my index? (Filtering over joined indexed views)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have two indexed views, `v_First` and `v_Second`.  These views work great when I have a `WHERE` clause that filters only based on one of these views, however as soon as I have filter criteria based on both views I get two clustered index scans and poor performance as a result.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.v_First (NOEXPAND)
JOIN dbo.v_Second (NOEXPAND)
ON dbo.v_First.id = dbo.v_Second.id
WHERE 
dbo.v_First.Firstname = 'JUSTIN'
OR dbo.v_Second.Surname = 'JUSTIN'
```

If I comment out either one of the above two `WHERE` clauses then I get lookups and the query performs so I know that individually I have the correct indexes defined.

Why does the query not perform when filtering based on multiple indexed views, and what can I do to fix it?

(Sorry, I can't post execution plans, they are trivial anyway - just two clustered index scans on the two respective views clustered index and a merge join)

**Update:**

**v_First** columns:

- ID (bigint, clustered index)
- FirstName (varchar(254), nonclustered index)

**v_Second** columns:

- ID (bigint, clustered index)
- Surname (varchar(254), nonclustered index)

All of the indexes contain only the single column.

**Update, the second:**

I've found that if the `OR` clause is changed to an `AND` clause, the query performs fine.  I've also found that if I change the query to use a `UNION` statement instead of a `OR` the query performs fine:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.v_First (NOEXPAND)
JOIN dbo.v_Second (NOEXPAND)
ON dbo.v_First.ID = dbo.v_Second.ID
WHERE dbo.v_First.Firstname = 'JUSTIN'
UNION SELECT * FROM dbo.v_First (NOEXPAND)
JOIN dbo.v_Second (NOEXPAND)
ON dbo.v_First.ID = dbo.v_Second.ID
WHERE dbo.v_Second.Surname = 'JUSTIN'
```

As far as I'm aware these two queries should be equivalent?

Finally, I've also found that using a subquery instead also has an odd effect, the following query performs fine:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.v_First (NOEXPAND)
-- JOIN dbo.v_Second (NOEXPAND)
-- ON dbo.v_First.ID = dbo.v_Second.ID
WHERE dbo.v_First.ID IN
(
      SELECT ID FROM dbo.v_Second (NOEXPAND)
      WHERE dbo.v_Second.Surname = 'JUSTIN'
)
OR dbo.v_First.Firstname = 'JUSTIN'
```

However if I uncomment the `JOIN` (so that I can obtain the columns from the second table in the results of my query) then I get a table scan on the v_Second clustered index (note however that is still better than the original query as it involves only 1 scan, instead of 2).

I'm very confused - what's going on?  It seems that I can work around these issues by "refactoring" my query, however I'm concerned that I don't understand what's going on here - I'd rather avoid making changes that I don't fully understand.

Comment: @OMG - Pretty much just the columns and indexes that are absolutely necessary to create an indexed view - I've updated my question.

Comment: Even with a table with just ID, Firstname, Surname, clustered on the ID and indexed on Firstname and Surname separately, a self-join along the lines of your query results in a similarly 'bad' looking query plan + slow execution.  Introducting a second table with the same schema as the first, and same indexes, doesn't improve the query.  Interesting.

Comment: One question: how may rows are there in the base table?

Comment: @gbn - There are ~3,000,000 rows in the base table, however these are filtered to around 1,000,000 in each of the views.  This is however only a sampling of data for investigating possible performance issues - the real data set will most likely to be in excess of 12 million records in the base table.

Answer (score 3):

Observations

- You have an "OR" condition which is not SARGable
- You may need to add ID to each index so it's available without scans/lookups
- I'd like to see the plans anyway. Use [`SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176058.aspx)

To answer your question, I'd probably have one index on the base table with both text columns and let it scan that. The OR does not give you many options and 2 indexed views is pointless IMHO. After your update, you have some contrived SQL constructs: do you really need 2 indexed views and a fancy derived table or UNION?

Comment: The indexed views are to work around some limitations of the base tables - its very strange and less than ideal - I'm investigating indexed views as a lesser-of-two-evils approach.